# Matlab gui error

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

this is a part of my gui which executes when i click on the push button

```
//
//
//
%VERIFICATION 
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton9.
function pushbutton9_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton9 (see GCBO)
DIR=handles.directory;  
%angle=Angles(DIR);
area=nor_area(DIR);
%area=0.002;
%display(area)
Check=verify(area);
%display(Check);
if(Check==0)
%message = sprintf('nClick the OK button to continue');
msgbox('The signature belongs to the same person!!!');
else
msgbox('The signature is forged!!!');
end

//
// 
//
```

and this is the verify function

```
//
//
//
function flag= verify(area)
%area=0.8969;
%take=area;
%display(take)
flag=0;
extract = xlsread('D:\Project\Image_processing\important\best.xlsx', 'CW4:CW17');
c=size(extract);
%display(c)
for k = 1:c
if (extract(k)==area)
      display(extract(k)); 
      flag=1;
    end 
end
%display(flag)
//
//
//
```

best.xlsx is the excel file from which I am retrieving the values and comparing with the value I get from the main gui function. The problem is even if I send the area value explicitly its not working. If I try running each function individually that is gui separately and verify separately it sets the flag correctly, but when I run it together it's not setting the flag properly.

Answer (score 0):

Take another look at the following lines in the `verify` function:

```
c = size(extract);
for k = 1:c
```

I presume you really want

```
c = numel(extract);
```

because `size` returns a vector.

Comment: `numel` returns the number of elements in an array. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/numel.html.

Comment: "??? Undefined function or method
'nume1' for input arguments of type
'double'." I am getting this error of i use that.

Comment: That's a letter `l` not a number `1`.

Comment: I tried with that it didnt work, The program as a separate module, in the sense, if i pass some value in 2 different modules, it returns the flag properly, but when i execute it together there is some problem, There is some problem with the linking , while passing and excepting it but not able to figure out that.

Comment: The problem is just with the "if" part of the verify function, is there any syntax error or something or in the way i have implemented it ?